# Complex Functions Examples

Tags: functions, solution-verification, real-numbers

I was asked to give an example of a function:

i) whose domain isn't equal to its codomain

ii) whose domain isn't equal to its image

iii) whose codomain isn't equal to its image

iv) a function $f$ from the real numbers to the real numbers such that $f\circ f = f$. Is this equal to the identity function?

My first thought was a function $f$ mapping from the real numbers to $[0, \infty)$ such that $f(x) = x^2$. Would this be a sufficient answer for i, ii, and iii?

For iv, I said $f$ maps the real numbers to the real numbers such that $f(x) = x$. Would $f(x) = 1$ also be acceptable?

Is my thinking correct for these questions?

Comment: The "complex" in the title is misleading.

Comment: Your first function $f(x)=x^2$ is sufficient for i and ii, but not iii.

Comment: @Randall That was my intention for more traffic, but I'll edit it if you want me to :)

Comment: @EnEm Yeah just realised after reading your message, silly error there. If I change the codomain of the same equation to the set of real numbers, it would be correct right ?

Comment: Yeah or you can make the codomain $[-1,\infty)$

Comment: @EnEm Just to confirm, was my thought for iv that that meant f has to be an identity function true ?

Comment: No it doesn't necessarily have to be the identity function, but yeah identity function works as well. Like your example also works, something like $f(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ also works

Comment: "Would $f(x) = 1$ be acceptable?" Can't you figure this out yourself? You just need to check that $f\circ f = f$. What is $f\circ f(x)$ for each $x$ for this function?

Comment: @PaulSinclair 1?

Comment: Yes, $f\circ f(x) = 1$ for all $x$. So is $f\circ f = f$?

Comment: Yeah that would be true